# Is there a way to transfer the state of tlmgr from texlive 2013 to 2014

Tags: texlive

Every year to get a not too big texlive directory and faster updates (less downloading), I manually remove a lot of packages.

Is there a simple way to get the operation done on year (for example for texlive 2013) and apply it to another year (texlive 2014)?

For example, I remove every packages containing asian extensions and it is somewhat boring to repeat it year after year.

Comment: does the time saved on download ever reclaim the time spent hand tuning the tlmgr config?

Comment: In the SSD age disk is also worth saving.

Comment: If you have specialized packages (e.g., Asian extensions...), consider installing them either in your personal TeX directory or in LOCALTEXMFHOME. Do not install them in the main TEXMF tree. That way, you won't need to touch them at all when switching from one TeXLive vintage to the next.